# How to Make objects "move" with pressing a specific key? - Processing

Tags: java, processing

I am new to programming and am having a problem with a simple pong application I am building. The idea is that player 1 controls the left and top paddle, while player 2 controls right and bottom. The program is not finished, but I have run into a problem. With my code right now the paddles either don't move at all or shift at a diagonal rather than moving left to right for both paddles. Help would be much appreciated and any pointers on how to fix or better organize my program would be appreciated. Thanks for your time and help.

```
package xpong;

import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PFont;
import processing.core.PImage;

public class XPong extends PApplet {
    PFont f;      
    public boolean sideMoveLeft = false;
    public boolean sideMoveRight = false;
    public boolean topMoveLeft = false;
    public boolean topMoveRight = false;
    public float speed = 5;

    public float x = 0;
    public float y = 0;
    public float a = 0;
    public float b = 0;
    public boolean sideMoving = false;
    public boolean topMoving = false;



    public void setup() {
        size(800, 700);
        background(255, 255, 255);
        f = createFont("Arial",16,true);
        smooth();
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(255, 255, 255);
        textFont(f,16);                 
        fill(0);

        text("Press Spacebar to Begin!",300, 350);

            //leftBar();
            //topBar();
            //rightBar();
            //bottomBar();


        //Checks to see if if players keys are pressed to start playing and draws he bar
                moveLeftAndRight();
                translate(x, y);
                leftBar();          
                rightBar();

            /*if(key == 'q' || key == 'w'){
                moveTopAndBottom();
                translate(x, y);

                topBar();
            }*/
    }   
//Draws the bars
    public void leftBar() {

    fill(0, 0, 0);
    rect(40, 260, 10, 200);

    }
    public void rightBar() {

        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(730, 260, 10, 200);        
    }

    public void topBar() {

        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(300, 40, 200, 10);     
    }
    public void bottomBar() {

        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(300, 650, 200, 10);        
    }
    // Checks for key press and tells the program user wants to move
    public void keyPressed(){
        if(key == 'q')
        {
            sideMoveLeft = true;
            topMoveLeft = true;
            sideMoving = true;
            topMoving = true;

        }
        if(key == 'w')
        {
            sideMoveRight = true;
            topMoveRight = true;
            sideMoving = true;
            topMoving = true;

        }
        if(key == 'o'){
            sideMoveLeft = true;
            sideMoving = true;

        }
        if(key == 'p'){
            sideMoveRight = true;
            sideMoving = true;

        }
    }
    //checks if the player has released the key to stop movement, and everything is set back to false
    public void keyReleased(){
        if(key == 'q')
        {
            sideMoveLeft = false;
            topMoveLeft = false;
            sideMoving = false;
            topMoving = false;
        }
        if(key == 'w')
        {
            sideMoveRight = false;
            topMoveRight = false;
            sideMoving = false;
            topMoving = false;
        }
        if(key == 'o'){
            sideMoveLeft = false;
            sideMoving = false;

        }
        if(key == 'p'){
            sideMoveRight = false;
            sideMoving = false;

        }
    }
    //checks to see if users is pressing key and adds 5(speed) to y
    public void moveLeftAndRight()
    {
        if(sideMoveRight)
        {
            y += speed;

        }
        if(sideMoveLeft)
        {
            y -= speed;

        }

 }
    //checks to see if users is pressing key and adds 5(speed) to x
    public void moveTopAndBottom()
    {
        if(topMoveRight)
        {
            x += speed;

        }
        if(topMoveLeft)
        {
            x -= speed;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: as a side note: you may want to use [`keyPressed()`](https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html) to handle keyboard inputs.

Comment: okay, thanks for the quick and helpful input.

Comment: If I'm wrong correct me, but processing by default includes an `update()` method. That method is called before `draw()` so you can put your logic methods in that block to give the game a smoother feel.

Comment: Now you check the key presses at two different locatoins: `keyPressed()` and `draw()`. This is a bad idea. In draw, you do not react to user input, you only react to your fileds (the boolean ones mainly). Are your panels still moving diagonally?

Comment: Yes, I tried to see if I could get the left and right paddles to work at least, but say player 1 keys are q and w, if I press them it moves player 2 paddles at the same time not independently. I have updated the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is within your `if`-cases:

```
if (key == 'q' || key == 'w') {
    moveLeftAndRight();
    translate(x, y);
    leftBar();
}
if (key == 'q' || key == 'w') {
    moveTopAndBottom();
    translate(a, b);
    topBar();
}
```

Both are the same, meaning: you enter the first `if` if and only if you enter the second `if`. This may cause the diagonal translation. I think you want to change the second `if` to:

```
if (key == 'w' || key == 's') {
    ...
}
```

Comment: The thing is my idea was that player 1 controls two bars with the same keys. So that instead of the ball bouncing back and forth it can bounce everywhere on all four sides.

Comment: Please add some comments to your program. I am not sure i understand each line and the whole call structure of your program. It is well possible that the `if`-cases are not the source of your problem.

Comment: Okay, I really didn't think much of comments, because I figured I am the only one looking at so I can  understand what is what, but I will make sure to comment more. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Is there any possible why to do this or do I need to assign different keys?

Comment: You do not NEED to define different key. I just tried to understand the semantics of your program. My way of thought was: If you have two `if`-cases with different body, then the condition should be different. Otherwise, you could use only one `if`.

Comment: I can try to explain the semantics of my messy and confusing program, if you would like?

Comment: As I said: add comments. They should explain it for everyone visible.

Comment: I add some comments, if you could still look at it would be great. If not thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed and update code and ignore commented code:

```
package xpong;


import processing.core.PApplet;
import processing.core.PFont;
import processing.core.PImage;
public class XPong extends PApplet {
//  PFont f;
    //public boolean alwaysTrue = true;

    public boolean p1SideMoveUp = false;
    public boolean p1SideMoveDown = false;
    public boolean p2SideMoveUp = false;
    public boolean p2SideMoveDown = false;
    public boolean p1moving = false;
    public boolean p2moving = false;

    public float speed = 5;
//  int ballSpeed = 10;

    public float p1X = 0;
    public float p1Y = 0;
    public float p2A = 0;
    public float p2B = 0;
  //  int ballX = 400;

  //  float theta;
  //  String message = "thelra;kdjfasdfadsf adfa";

    public void setup() {

    //  size(800, 700);
    //  f = createFont("Arial",16,true);
        smooth();
    }

    public void draw() {
        background(255, 255, 255);
        //screenDivider();

        //textFont(f,16);
        //fill(0);
      //  text("Hello Strings!",10,100);

        moveRight();
        moveLeft(); 
    //ballX = ballX + ballSpeed;

    /*if ((ballX > width) || (ballX < 0)) {

        ballSpeed = ballSpeed * -1;
    }*/
      //stroke(0);
      //fill(175);
     // ellipse(ballX,350,32,32);
}   
    public void moveLeft(){
        moveP1Paddle();
        p1BarDraw();
    }
    public void moveRight(){
        moveP2Paddle();
        p2BarDraw();
    }

//Draws the bars
    public void p1BarDraw() {

    fill(0, 0, 0);
    rect(p1X + 40, p1Y + 260, 10, 200);

    }
    public void p2BarDraw() {

        fill(0, 0, 0);
        rect(p2A + 730, p2B + 260, 10, 200);        
    }
    /*public void screenDivider() {
        line(400, 10000, 400, 0);
    }*/

    // Checks for key press and tells the program user wants to move
    public void keyPressed(){
        if(key == 'q')
        {
            p1SideMoveUp = true;
        }
        if(key == 'w')
        {
            p1SideMoveDown = true;
        }
        if(key == 'o'){
            p2SideMoveUp = true;
        }
        if(key == 'p'){
            p2SideMoveDown = true;
        }
    }
    //checks if the player has released the key to stop movement, and everything is set back to false
    public void keyReleased(){
        if(key == 'q')
        {
            p1SideMoveUp = false;
        }
        if(key == 'w')
        {
            p1SideMoveDown = false;
        }
        if(key == 'o'){
            p2SideMoveUp = false;
        }
        if(key == 'p'){
            p2SideMoveDown = false;
        }
    }
    //checks to see if users is pressing key and adds speed to y
    public void moveP1Paddle()
    {
        if(p1SideMoveDown){
            p1Y += speed;
        }
        if(p1SideMoveUp){
            p1Y -= speed; 
        }

 }
    public void moveP2Paddle()
    {
        if(p2SideMoveDown){
            p2B += speed;
        }
        if(p2SideMoveUp){
            p2B -= speed;
        }
    }
}
```